# Java Application unresponsive

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump

I have a Java application running on payara server in a VM with 2 GB memory. Fixed Heap allocated is 1GB and the jvm options `-XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -Xmx1024m`. Application features includes pulling data from a queue on another server and answering Http requests from outside clients.

We are facing unresponsiveness problem on this app. Restarting the server fixes the problem. Faced this issue for a couple of times.

We have collected heap dump and the dump's size is just 170 MB. Is the dump size OK? Moreover the dump is not showing any valuable memory leak info, just showing problem suspects as ConnectorClassFinder of sun package (just occupying 55 MB). So couldn't confirm  if this an OutOfMemory problem or not. Can I get some help on this to proceed further?

Comment: What tool are you using to analyze the dumpfile.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, Eclipse MAT

Comment: Well do you actually get an out-of-memory error?  Have you tried to monitor the app in real-time with visual-vm or similar?

Comment: @OldProgrammer We couldn't monitor the app in real-time as this happens only with our production env, where we wouldn't be allowed to monitor. Moreover it didn't throw any out-of-memory error. But still it goes unresponsive, though the network is fine.

Comment: @sheikhisham did you find root cause of this? we are seeing similar symptoms with no indication in logs and/or dump.